# Term for PA music before a concert starts

Tags: terminology, concert

I have been to a number of rock concerts.  By and large, during the time before the show starts, music is typically played on the PA system.  For rock concerts, the PA music is usually the same genre, blended with classic rock favorites.

My question is, what is the term for this PA music?  Overture comes to mind, but I believe an overture is performed by the artist which you went to attend.  "House music" also comes to mind (since, when the concert is done, you bring up the "house lights"), but I don't think that is quite right either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen this referred as *pre-show* and *post-show* music, which sets the mood for the performance for eg.

[Example 1](http://www.theatreface.com/profiles/blogs/the-point-of-preshow)

[Example 2](http://ajournalofmusicalthings.com/pre-showpost-show-music/)

Comment: I know a theater design major and arranging the *pre-show* and *post-show* of a production is the job of the sound designer.

Comment: This is possibly the best sourced answer I've ever gotten on this network.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Us audio guys call it "walk-in music." A lot of the time, the tracks we play are at our discretion - but sometimes the client/producer will provide specific tracks. Obviously, the post-show is called "walk-out."